# Show that $R[X,Y]/(X^2,Y) = R[X]/(X^2)$

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to show that $R[X,Y]/(X^2,Y) = R[X]/(X^2)$.

I tried this:

$$R[X,Y]/(X^2,Y)=(R[X])[Y]/(X^2,Y)=\frac{(R[X])[Y]/(Y)}{(X^2,Y)/(Y)}=\frac{R[X]}{(X^2,Y)/(Y)}\overset{?}{=}R[X]/(X^2)$$

I know that $(X^2,Y)/(Y)=(X^2)/((X^2)∩(Y))$. But I don't think that $(X^2)∩(Y)=(0)$

or I thought about :

$$(R[X])(Y)/(X^2,Y)\overset{?}{=}\frac{(R[X])(Y)/(Y)}{(X^2)}=R[X]/(X^2)$$

But I don't know if it is in general true that $R/(a,b)=(R/(a))/(b)$.

Comment: Have you looked at the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem? My gut tells me this will get you that last statement.

Comment: @EricStucky You mean, that this is true:$R/(a,b)=(R/(a))/(b)$ ?

Comment: Yes. The notation there is a bit misleading because $(b)$ is only an ideal over $R/(a)$, so it is not quite the $(b)$ that first jumps to mind. There might be a way to exploit that and make the connection most clear.

Comment: @EricStucky I don't see how the 4th isomorphism theorem helps here.

Comment: Hm, I'm not having any luck with it; maybe 4IT doesn't work. If it's not too painful to abandon the work you've done so far, then Laurent's solution is pretty straightforward. (Hah, I didn't see your comment until just now :P)

Comment: @EricStucky 1) It's too painfull. 2) I want to know if it is in general true, that if I quotient with the ideal $(a,b)$ if I can first look at the quotient with $(a)$ and then look at the quotient  with $(b)$.

Comment: @EricStucky I think it is: $aR+bR/aR = bR/aR = b (R/aR)$ so then you have $(a,b)/(a)=[b]$ where $[b]=b (R/aR)$ the ideal generated in $R/aR$. Therefore using the third isomorphism theorem, we get $R/(a,b)=(R/(a))/((a,b)/(a))=(R/(a))/[b]$ where $[b]$ is the ideal generated in $R/(a)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\varphi:R[x,y]\to R[x]/(x^2)$, simply mapping a polynomial $p(x,y)$ to its reduction modulo $y$, so that you only have a polynomial in $x$, then reducing modulo $x^2$, so that you only have a linear factor left. It is clear that it is surjective. $\ker\varphi$ is obviously $(x^2,y)$, so you get
$$
R[x,y]/(x^2,y)\cong R[x]/(x^2).
$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know of something like this is true: $R/(a,b)=(R/(a))/(b)$ ?

Comment: Use a map $\varphi:R\to (R/(a))/(b)$, sending an element $x$ to its reduction modulo $(a)$, then reducing modulo $(b)$, i.e. the composition $R\to R/(a)\to (R/(a))\to (R/(a))/(b)$. What is the kernel of the map? an element $x$ is zero in the quotient if and only if it was in either of the two ideals you quotiented by, either $x\in(a)$, or $x+(a)\in (a)+(b)$, which is exactly $(a,b)$. Or if you want to go faster, you might say $(a)+(b)=(a,b)$, so cosets $x+(a,b)$ are exactly $x+(a)+(b)$...